# Regular expression: when every alternate character is a digit

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to write a Linux command using `egrep` that validates lines whose even character is a number.

I am doing it this way:

```
egrep "^(.[0-9])*$" text.txt
```

However, this fails for i) empty lines and ii) cases where the number of characters is odd. It should match `123` since the only odd position is indeed a number, but it doesn't.

Valid patterns:

```
a2b4c6
000000
123
a1b
a1b2c3q
```

Invalid patterns:

```
aaaa
0a0a0a
a1bq
```

Could anyone please tell me what mistake I am making?

EDIT: The only restriction is that every alternate character needs to be even; the length of the entire line might be even or odd. The command above only allows even length ex: 1234,a1b2c3 etc but even 123,a1b are valid but this doesn't match them. My question is: How to handle this?

Comment: `*` matches _zero_ or more occurrences, try with `+`

Comment: The mistake you are making is posting a command, without example input that doesn't work with the solution you have (which you provided) and also leaving out the output that you are getting based on that input and the command. Please update your post with that information, and suppress any urge to include EDIT/UPDATE in the text when you do so. It is also quite a good idea to read at least the help->tour

Comment: @Anthon I have included valid and invalid cases

Comment: what's wrong with what you've got? is your problem that you're also turning up blank lines? if so, just do what @don_crissti suggests. else, I can't see how it would fail... unless you also want to handle lines with an odd number of characters, in which case you need to add `.?` just before the `$`. You might also drop `^` and `$` and use `-x`.

Comment: What Anthon and mikeserv said; in case you *don't want* odd characters to be numbers, `egrep '^([^0-9][0-9])+$' file.txt`

Comment: What you show should work for anything except blank lines as far as I ca tell. Please [edit] your question and explain _why_ it fails. The command returns exactly what you seem to be expecting when run on the examples you show.

Comment: @terdon The expression does not handle the case when the expression is odd for example 1234 fails it, how to handle it?

Comment: @kos The expression does not handle the case when the expression is odd for example 1234 fails it, how to handle it?

Comment: As opposed to your mention of "even characters" describing characters number 2, 4, 6, ... I mentioned "odd characters" to describe characters number 1, 3, 5, ... . So my expression is meant to match only lines whose "even characters" are numbers and "odd characters" are not numbers, such as "a1a1a1", "b2b2b2", "c3c3c3", ... and not, e.g., "111111", "bbbbbb", "1c1c1c", ... . If neither this nor what Anthon and mikeserv suggested is what you want, please explain it again and post more examples, because your current wording / examples are a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @Mathew then, please [edit] your question as you've already been asked to do, and show us the examples where it fails. Give us an example file and show us your desired output. I don't see why `1234` is "odd" nor why your regex wouldn't match it. It will be impossible to help you unless you edit and show us specific examples.

Comment: @terdon i am sorry that was a typo, i meant 123 fails the it, and I wanted to know how to handle it. In general it doesn't capture when there are odd no of characters

Comment: Yes, I understood (finally). Next time, please make sure to include an example of your input and desired output and to explain precisely how your command fails. Don't try and clarify in the comments, are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. All relevant information needs to be in the question itself. Anyway, have a look at my answer, I hope it helps and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression will match empty lines because `*` means "zero or more" so `^(.[0-9])*$` matches on an empty line. You can fix that by using `+` ("match 1 or more") instead.

Your next problem is that you don't match if the number of characters on a line is even. To avoid that, you can tell `grep` to also allow 0 or 1 character at the very end:

```
grep -E "^(.[0-9])+.?$"
```

For example:

```
$ cat file 
a2b4c6
000000


123
aaaa
0a0a0a

$ grep -E "^(.[0-9])+.?$" file
a2b4c6
000000
123
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, what would i need to do if i want to include empty line and single characters ?(not part of question, was just curious)